# the volume of the tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, volume

How can I prove the following statement?

> Prove that the volume of the tetrahedron formed by four non-coplanar points $A_i=(x_i,y_i,z_i),$ $1 \le i \le 4$, is equal to $\frac{1}{6} \left| \overrightarrow{A_1 A_2} \times \overrightarrow{A_1 A_3} .\overrightarrow{A_1 A_4}\right|.$

we did volume of the paralelogram at the before lesson and this is our homework but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I edited your post to put the equations in the image into mathjax. I hope you don't mind. As it stands, this is a "problem statement question", which is generally frowned upon. Can you edit the post to elaborate more about what concepts you know that might be relevant, what you have tried, and so on? I know it can be difficult if you don't know where to start, but this process will be helpful for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the volume of a tetrahedron is $V={1\over3}A_bh$ where $A_b$ is the area of the base and $h$ is the height from the base to the opposite vertex. If $\overrightarrow{A_1}$, $\overrightarrow{A_2}$ and $\overrightarrow{A_3}$ are the vectors pointing the vertex of the base, then $\overrightarrow{A_1 A_2}=\vec a$, $\overrightarrow{A_1 A_3}=\vec b$ and $\overrightarrow{A_2 A_3}=\vec c$ are the vectors along the base sides with mignitude $a$, $b$, $c$ respectively; so you can write the area of the base (it is a triangle) as:

$$A_b={1\over2}a b\sin\gamma=\left({1\over2}a c\sin\beta={1\over2}bc\sin\alpha\right)$$

so we have $A_b={1\over2}|\vec a\times \vec b|$.

The vector $\vec {A_b}$ is normal to the base and thus parallel to $h$; hence we can project $\overrightarrow{A_1 A_4}=\vec d$ (the vector from the vertex "1" to the apex of the tetrahedron) along $\vec {A_b}$ to obtain $h$:

$$h=\vec d|\cos\delta|$$

where $\delta$ is the angle between $\overrightarrow{A_1 A_4}=\vec d$ and the height (or we can say, the direction of $\vec {A_b}$). I put $|\cos\delta|$ because $\vec {A_b}$ might be upwards or downwards, so the angle could be $\delta$ or $\pi-\delta$ and $|\cos\delta|=|\cos(\pi-\delta)|$.

The volume will be:

$$V={1\over3}{1\over2}|\vec a\times \vec b|d|\cos\delta|={1\over6}d|\vec a\times \vec b||\cos\delta|={1\over6}|\vec d\cdot (\vec a\times \vec b)|={1\over6}|\overrightarrow{A_1 A_4}\cdot (\overrightarrow{A_1 A_2}\times \overrightarrow{A_1 A_3})|$$